How to enable PWA push notifications in App Store?
I have PWA app packaged with PWABuilder the app is now in App Store that works fine, but Notifications are not allowed, they work in the browser - I saw that there is a Firebase that can help to fix it, but I am wondering how the message will be sent to the users? Will I be able to continue using the web push notifications that I have? I need to send them to specific user not to all of them.
Also the reference to any guide will be appriciated.

If you have converted a PWA to an App Store app then you will need to use App Store pushes. Your app needs to obtain the device token on launch and register that in your back end. You can then send push notifications to that token, either by using the Apple service directly or via a 3rd party (FCM is one such)
